# Relating map positions

Tags: php, gis, adobe-illustrator

I initially asked a question, but it was not clear. Here is the scenario:

We have a topographical map of small district. We also have a demographic distribution of the same region and a general map of the region depicting the roads and other man-made infrastructure. We have to use the topographical map as the base map such that when the user marks a location on the map it will appear marked on the other 2 maps.

Any suggestions on the platform to use and how to merge the maps to be viewable on a browser like Google Maps, switching from the satellite view to map view.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done using the Google or Bing Maps API. Although, you would need a good understanding of javascript / geocoding / Parsing web service results.  in order to accomplish what you need.

[Here are Bing maps developer resources](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/developers/web.aspx)

[Here is the interactive SDK to get familiar with their libraries.](http://www.bingmapsportal.com/isdk/ajaxv7#CreateMap1)

[Here is a hand full of more useful features thanks to Mike Garza, not included in the SDK](http://www.garzilla.net/vemaps/Draggable-Polygon-with-Bing-Maps-7.aspx)

Keep in mind, between v6.3 and 7.0 there was quite the change in library names / syntax.